# cryptography with python, it is for a project

Tags: python

I need some help creating cryptography code for python. i have some code myself but if someone can add to it and maybe and some brute force techniques that could help a lot thanks.

```
def crypto():
   for character in range(0,256):
       print chr(character)


def Caesar_Encrypt (plaintext, key):
   cipher = ""
   for index in range(0, len(plaintext)):
       cipher += chr((ord(plaintext[index]) + key) % 256)
   return cipher

def Caesar_Decrypt (cipher,key):
   plaintext = ""
   for index in range(0, len(cipher)):
       plaintext += chr((ord(cipher[index]) - key) % 256)
   return plaintext
def main():
   crypto()
```

Comment: This is way too broad... what are you specifically asking?

Comment: Here's a neat free book called [Hacking Secret Ciphers with Python](https://inventwithpython.com/hacking/) that might help you out.